# User was able to award a bounty to himself

Tags: support, bounties

The [FAQs on the bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) seem to indicate that users cannot award bounties to themselves.

However, [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5468709/dave?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=1) seems to have done this for [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640220/why-is-my-entity-not-evicted-from-my-second-level-cache/35850038#35850038) to [their own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640220/why-is-my-entity-not-evicted-from-my-second-level-cache).

The reputation log and the graph both show the reputation increasing over the last two days.

Is this valid? If not, can the breach be fixed please?

Comment: Looks more like a bug.

Comment: Mhm, @Sha don't identicons get generated once per email address? If so, that would mean we've got two accounts with the same login credentials but different user IDs. Suspicious?

Comment: @IͶΔ nope, they are different. [One](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/87d3fbb8e0345cb7a956592180d862c1?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1) and [two](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9f460ae7deb6fa19034c810a53b9fbac?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG) - looks valid to me. I usually would have noticed that, guess Den was too distracting... :( *crying over lost rep ;)*

Answer (score 11):

Going by display names alone I can see how you would think this. But looking carefully at the accounts used to ask/answer the question and post the bounty (using either the [question's revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35640220/revisions) or, better yet, the [question's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35640220/timeline)) should clear things up.<sup>*</sup>

- The UID of the account that asked the question and posted the bounty-winning answer is [5468709](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5468709).
- The UID of the account that posted the bounty is [1235929](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235929).

So different accounts are involved.

Is it *possible* that the same person controls both accounts, though without access to PII one would be unable to conclude this. For completeness' sake, [there are currently over 2000 accounts on SO with the display name "Dave"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/447489).

---

<sup>*</sup><sub>The answer has since been deleted, making it difficult for users with <10K rep on SO to verify these facts. So... trust me?</sub>

Comment: Huh! No idea how I missed that... Detective Fischer sounds just fitting. ;)

Comment: You'd think that someone abusing the system with two accounts would have the smarts to choose different usernames for both...

Comment: Well, answer with bounty has been deleted by a moderator so guess it's the same person after all. :) /cc @Carpetsmoker

Comment: @ShadowWizard If an mod has concluded that sockpuppetry has occurred, I think it's a bit odd that neither account has been suspended, or deleted. Maybe a warning has been issued, but there's still potential for abuse.

Comment: @arthur agree, I even asked the mod in chat, but he kept silent. Maybe one-time slip that has been forgiven, so better keep an eye.

Comment: @Shadow it's been dealt with - although the effect is that it's made this meta question and answer even more confusing :)

Comment: @Jon that's just teasing! *sadface*